# How to check if a character is a letter of some alphabet?

Tags: c++, locale, alphabet

How to check in C++ if a character is a letter of some alphabet?
Generally I need something like this:

```
bool is_german(wchar_t ch);
bool is_russian(wchar_t ch);
bool is_japanese(wchar_t ch);
```

and etc.

**EDIT 1**. Can I do it without defining all charachter sets of all languages I need. Or maybe there is some library which has somethis like this:

> std::vector alphabet = GetEnglishAlphabet(); // alphabet =
>   {L'a', L'b', L'c', ...}

**EDIT 2**. If someone is interested in I've found

> Script QChar::script() const

Comment: I'm not sure that's a well-defined concept. Is `.` English? Is `$`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, no. This is punctuation.

Comment: Are you asking for an `STL` or `c++stdlib` type of functionality that exists to check if a specific character is of a specific language? Or are you asking how to roll your own?

Comment: @txtechhelp, I accept any library functionality.

Comment: Most any solution to this problem is likely to be a naïve solution.  You wouldn't want a broken solution to appear on your résumé, or in an  exposé of your programming skills, lest it be discovered that you've been putting up a grand façade.  When that happens you'll likely find yourself served up as the main entrée at a code review. (tongue in cheek, of course)

Comment: @DavidO, see my edit to post. Maybe that will be OK?

Comment: I'm curious what problem is actually being solved. Are you trying to guess what language a document might be written in?  Or is determining a given language's alphabet really the ultimate goal?  (Just curiosity)

Comment: Are you working with Unicode? If so, I think the specification lays out which code points go with which character sets. For example in UTF-8, Latin characters are from 0x000-0x24F, Greek and Coptic are from 0x370-0x3FF, etc.

Comment: One issue is that of combining marks.  I think the first thing you have to do is normalize your Unicode input, and deal with entities as grapheme clusters rather than as individual wchar_t code points.  Once you've done that, the next step is to determine what Unicode properties the given grapheme cluster has.  That will take you a few steps in the right direction.  But there are some serious challenges to overcome here if you want to take any random grapheme cluster and decide what alphabets it could belong to.

Comment: @DavidO, I want to determine if a message from user is acceptable (in the language he set).

Comment: @user1118321, I want not just Greek, Corpic, Cyrillic, but English, German, French.

Comment: In our Unicode world you simply cannot reliably verify that a given block of text is using only letters that are valid for a given language unless you want to enumerate for each language those letters you care to accept... and even that is bound to miss legitimate graphemes.  The best you can hope for is a pretty good guess, and even that is not trivial.

Comment: @VALOD9 What do you do when the user inputs a response in more than one language? What if they enter, "Yes, Oui, Si" or something like that?

Comment: @user1118321, it is a hypothetical task. I won't use this in real life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::isalpha` defined in `<locale>`. Remember to set to the correct locale first
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/isalpha/

EDIT:

```
std::locale loc("en-US");
bool isAlpha1 = std::isalpha('a', loc);
bool isAlpha2 = std::isalpha('&', loc);
bool isAlpha3 = std::isalpha('1', loc);
bool isAlpha4 = std::isalpha('Ж', loc); //cyrilic alphabet, but not US
```

You can find Language strings here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/goglobal/bb896001.aspx

Comment: setting the locale and checking if a specific character `isalpha` won't tell if you the character is of a specific language. Setting the locale also affects more than just your local function depending on how you set your locale (i.e. `LC_ALL`).

Comment: Reading from the link: `isalpha - Check if character is alphabetic` Reading from the questionnaire: `How to check in C++ if a character is a letter of some alphabet?` In my opinion the function gives what the questionnaire wants

Comment: Further more, std::locale is an object containing locale information. It does not affect or reset the system.

Comment: can you please post an example of how to use the `setlocale` function mixed with the `std::isalpha` function to retrieve if a specific unicode character is of the `German` or `Japanese` languages?

Comment: Example added. Germany would be `de-DE`, Japanese would be `ja-JP`

Comment: What if the specific locale is not installed?

Comment: Two options: Install the locale or ignore specific language in your application.

Comment: I think adding comments that contain the expected value for each line would be good.

Answer (score 2):

For a roll-your-own solution, I would generally expect something like this:

```
vector<wchar_t> german = {... german chars ...};
vector<wchar_t> japanese = {... japanese chars ...};
vector<wchar_t> russian = {... russian chars ...};

bool is_in_alphabet(const vector<wchar_t>& language, wchar_t candidate) {
   return std::find(language.begin(), language.end(), candidate) != language.end();
}
```

Comment: I see... then that's out of my area of expertise, I don't know about language libraries that provide this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There is also ICU library, having [ublock_getCode](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/uchar_8h.html#a4e77b605d178b6b79638e5bea57927df) function. Note however that you can't tell the exact language, since same letters are used in different alphabets.